# AWS Cloudformation quick-create link is not reading parameters in URL

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

As per the documentation[1], I've created a quick-create link to create a simple stack in AWS cloud formation. The stack configuration YAML file is hosted on s3[2]. It creates a stack required as part of an onboarding process for a new developer tool I'm building[3].

I am using the following link:

> https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=eu-west-2#/stacks/new?stackName=CBill-slack-bot&param_UserId=1&param_VersionToken=TL3K3DK3K:R2D2H001&templateURL=https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cbill-stack-files/CBillReadOnlyAndBillingRole-TL3K3DK3K_R2D2H00F

However, the parameters `UserId` and `VersionToken` are not being populated when I click the link.

I've gone thoroughly through the documentation and have tested different tweaks for a few hours without success. The last thing to test would be to convert my YAML file to JSON and see if it works (although that would take me a while). Any help would be appreciated.

1: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-create-stacks-quick-create-links.html

2: https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cbill-stack-files/CBillReadOnlyAndBillingRole-TL3K3DK3K_R2D2H00F

3: https://computebill.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quick create URL is a bit different from the example given in the docs. The part before the query parameters should be `stacks/create/review?` instead of `stacks/new?`

The following link should work:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=eu-west-2#/stacks/create/review?stackName=CBill-slack-bot&param_UserId=1&param_VersionToken=TL3K3DK3K:R2D2H001&templateURL=https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cbill-stack-files/CBillReadOnlyAndBillingRole-TL3K3DK3K_R2D2H00F